# multiple @id annotations in a single entity

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-annotations

What is the difference between using multiple @Id in an entity Vs, Composite Id ?

Also, how does this @EmbeddedId work when there is no table actually created separately for the Embedded Object?

Comment: Considering this example : @Entity
class User {
@EmbeddedId UserId id;
Integer age;
} , let say I understand that @EmbeddedId id representation of the embedded class, why another annotation @EmbeddedId, why Can't I Simply use the same @Id ? any thing special with this Annotation ?

Comment: If I look at below example little bit more deep, class User {
@EmbeddedId UserId id;
Integer age;
}
@Embeddable
class UserId implements Serializable {
String firstName;
String lastName;
} , does it makes the Entire UserId as the Id column in the Embedded class User ?

Comment: also why do we have multiple @Id in an entity ? why can't we use @IdClass instead ?

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate offers different options for defining/using composite identifiers. All these options are explained in depth in the hibernate reference manual: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e4819.